# How to disable disk device user-friendly names in a RHEL 7 kickstart file

Tags: linux, redhat, kickstart, rhel7, multipath

We're right now in the process of deploying a set of fibre-channel connected hosts with multipathed root disks. The installation is automated through foreman, so we boot vie PXE and run anaconda with a kickstart file.

The default behaviour in anaconda is nowadays to use so-called user-friendly-names for multipath-devices (i.e. mpatha, mpathb, etc.). We would like to disable this behaviour so we have disks named by wwn.

As far as I understand the anaconda source-code there is a parameter/command called `mpath_friendly_names`, that can be used to *enable* friendly names (which is today's default). However, we want to *disable* friendly names and I cannot figure out what parameter/command in the kickstart will do that.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it necessary to avoid it during the kickstart process, or is it that you want to disable it for good *after* the installation?

Comment: We want to disable it during installation. As a fallback we already figured out we could disable it in a %post script.

Answer (score 0):

try passing to the booting kernel (i.e. within the `append` line if you use pxelinux)

```
inst.mpathFriendlyNames=0
```

EDIT: this parameters is used when processing flags at `/pyanaconda/flags.py`

Initially processed flags can get their default value overwritten if the right variable is found when parsing the Kernel command line.

In this case it overwrites the default value `self.mpathFriendlyNames = true`

Comment: I'd add an explanation on how this parameter behaves (and possibly if there's some limitations on when it's available). Just for completeness. :)

Comment: We tested this and a few variants of this. Your suggestions leads to anaconda finding no disks at all. Everything else we tried just had zero effect.

Comment: then you found a bug... try to see your Anaconda scripts.